# MVC "Get" Multiple Checkboxlist Values with same name from querystring, retrieve via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

Generated URL after the form has been submitted:

```
http://localhost/Search/Index?selectedOrganisationId=26195&selectedOrganisationId=26244
```

I have a form that is doing a Get Request.  I have several hidden fields that are storing id's for a selected organisation ids.  The parameter name in the querystring (selectedOrganisationId) is using the same name.

I've checked through StackOverflow and all the solutions seem to only bring back the last value in the querystring (26244) for that given name.

How can I get them all into an array?  Is this possible?

MVC handles it and picks up on it perfectly through the Controller -> Action.

Comment: you cannot send query parameter with same name multiple times. You have to send them with some delimitor like '-' and then split it in your code.

Comment: Well, you should do something like `selectedOrgainsationId[]=26195&selectedOrganisationId[]=26244`, and then you'll have an array of values when you `GET` that parameter.

Comment: @TwiStar - can you give an example in javascript on how I would get those values from the querystring as an array?

Comment: you should also consider using POST instead of GET ;)

Comment: @pinoniq it's for a search - Get is much better than using a post.  I need to be able to persist the search parameters for paging etc if the user clicks the back button to get to a previous page.

Comment: Ah, read to fast, apologies ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that springs to mind is to parse the query string from `window.location.search` - something like:

```
// a plain old javascript object (dictionary) to store the query string
var querystring = {};

// * 'window.location.search' is the query string of the current browser page
// * replace(regex, function) is a method of string that takes 
//    - a regular expression (between two forward slashes, the 'g' means global,
//      i.e. do more than just one replace) that matches `abc=123`
//    - a function that is called for each pattern match

window.location.search.replace(/([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?/g, function($1, $2, $3, $4) {
    // $1 to $4 are arguments that catch the groups in the regex.
    // Only $2 and $4 are of interest.

    // If we already have seen this value append (push) it on to the array
    if ($.isArray(querystring[$2]))
        querystring[$2].push($4);
    else 
        // otherwise create a new array with the found item
        querystring[$2] = [$4];
});

console.log(querystring);
console.log(querystring.selectedOrganisationId); // an array
```

The regular expression was borrowed from [this article](http://stevenbenner.com/2010/03/javascript-regex-trick-parse-a-query-string-into-an-object/), but the code extended to take into account multiple query string items with the same name.

Comment: Can you explain what the above is doing?

Comment: Thanks Duncan, much appreciated.  Makes more sense now.  Will look at the article too.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form id="organizations" method="GET" action="/Search/Index">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedOrganisationId[]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedOrganisationId[]" value="2">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

You'll get your desired result if you simply submit the form. If you want to get the response through an Ajax call, do this (using JQuery library):

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#organizations").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr("action"),
                data: form.serialize(),
                type: form.attr("method")   
            }).done(function(data){
                 //if success
                 console.log (data); 
            }).fail(function(){
                 console.log ("something is wrong!");
            })
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is after I have submitted the form the selectedOrganisationId values are appended to the querystring.  It's after the form has submitted that I need to get the values from the QueryString to populate a knockout observable array.

Comment: You can populate observable array inside a `done` method call, without reloading the page. Otherwise, you can generate knockout.js server-side using response from your controller.

Comment: I don't want to submit the search using ajax.  Therefore the done method call won't work.  The latter suggestion may be work.